# php merge, delete and keep order of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, merge, compare

I have two arrays something like this

```
1) array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "max" [1]=> string(3) "min" [2]=> string(3) "med" } 

2) array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "max" [1]=> string(3) "min" [2]=> string(4) "other" [3]=> string(3) "med" }
```

now i want to merge and delete the double entries of the two arrays, important thing is here to keep the order of the first array in the final array (max,min,med -> from first array, and then all others from second array)

the two arrays have different lengths array(3) and array(4)

```
$myfinalarray = (array_unique(array_merge($arr_first, $arr_last)));
```

the problem is the order is lost

result:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "max" [1]=> string(3) "min" [2]=> string(4) "other" [3]=> string(3) "med" } 
what i need is this
array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "max" [1]=> string(3) "min" [2]=> string(3) "med" [3]=> string(4) "other" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should erase the double entries from 2nd array first:

```
$array_last = array_diff($arr_last, $arr_first);
```

and then

```
$myfinalarray = (array_unique(array_merge($arr_first, $arr_last)));
```

Comment: i didnt try array_diff and the 2nd as first, but it works fine now thx

Comment: Wrong! array_unique erases double entries from arrays. both arrays could still have double entries ;)

Answer (score 0):

Order is not lost, but if you want to sort array in alphabetical order use `sort` function

```
$myfinalarray=sort($myfinalarray);
```

Comment: I doubt that is the answer Jim was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code,

```
  <?php
$arr1=array(0 => "max",1 => "min",2 => "med"); 

$arr3=array(0 => "max",1 => "min",2 => "other",3 =>"med");

$myfinalarray = (array_unique(array_merge($arr1, $arr3)));  
print_r($myfinalarray);
?>
```

the output willbe like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => max
    [1] => min
    [2] => med
    [5] => other
)
```

[check here](http://codepad.org/w39WW9MM)